# Addition of angular momenta with relative coefficients

Tags: angular-momentum, representation-theory

Suppose I wish to add angular momenta with some relative coefficients

$$\vec{J} = \alpha \vec{J}_1 + \beta \vec{J}_2$$
Can any one explain how this would be done? And how different would it be from the usual case of $\alpha = \beta = 1$?

Comment: What does this mean, though? Why do you need $\alpha$ and $\beta$, when $\vec{J}_1$ and $\vec{J}_2$ are angular momentum operators?  There's no guarantee that $\alpha\vec{J}_1+\beta\vec{J}_2$ even satisfies the commutation relations for it to be an angular momentum (I believe that it doesn't). Why do you want to do this?

Comment: @march Suppose there are two particles that have different magnetic moment and I wish to add their angular momenta. In that context we will have this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, assuming these represent rotation of a tensor product space, so operators of different subscripts commute, and they satisfy the rotation group Lie algebra,
$$
[J^a_i,J^b_j]=i\epsilon^{abc} J^c_i ~\delta_{ij},
$$
you see that your $\vec J$ fails to satisfy the same algebra,
$$
[J^a,J^b]=i\epsilon^{abc}( \alpha^2 J^c_1+ \beta^2 J^c_2) \neq i\epsilon^{abc} J^c,
$$
so it does not represent a rotation!

---

***Edit pursuant to comment by OP***

Its grim karma to use your confusing definition of *J*. Let's, instead, call it $\vec \mu= \alpha \vec J_1+ \beta \vec J_2$, and the ***true*** total angular momentum $\vec {\cal J}= \vec J_1+  \vec J_2$ which *does* satisfy the angular momentum Lie algebra. Nevertheless, your $\vec \mu$   is a fine *vector operator*,
$$
[\mu^a, {\cal J}^b]=i\epsilon^{abc} \mu^c,
$$
so its matrix elements for a given rotation representation *j*
transform simply by the [Wigner-Eckart theorem's](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Land%C3%A9_g-factor#A_derivation) projection theorem:
$$
\langle jm'|\mu^q|jm\rangle = \frac{\langle jm|\vec {\cal J}\cdot \vec \mu  |jm\rangle}{j(j+1)} \quad\langle jm'|{\cal J}^q|jm\rangle, 
$$
where the essential orientation-dependence  is carried by ${\cal J}$ of the second factor on the r.h.s., only, as the first factor does not depend on it (*m*) and is *the same* for the entire (2*j*+1)-dimensional multiplet; that's what makes it "reduced".

I have skipped any and all "other" quantum numbers, to keep things simple, but you may slip them into the reduced matrix element. The text by Sakurai & Napolitano, (3.483), has a fine discussion of that. So there is *some* predictability in the rotation of your vector operator.

Comment: So how will we add angular momenta of two particles with different magnetic moments? That is not possible then?

Comment: You add the magnetic moments, and you get a net magnetic moment for each representation; what do you do for constituent quarks? Maybe you wish to rewrite your question with context?

Comment: [WP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Landé_g-factor).

Comment: The sum you wrote down is *not* an angular momentum, and, like magnetic moments, points in a different direction than the total angular momentum, in general. Nevertheless, it is a vector operator, so you may determine its matrix elements through the Wigner-Eckart theorem!! Is that what you are asking about?

Comment: But Wigner-Eckart theorem is about the dot product of the angular moment right?

Comment: Ok. It seems this Wigner-Eckart theorem is what I probably need to read a bit about.

Comment: [Hyperphysics](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/quantum/Lande.html#c2).

Comment: Thank you so much. I am much obliged.